# Paste comma separated list into EditText and store in SQLite TABLE on multiple rows

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm wondering how to paste a comma separated list (test1,test2,test3,test4) in an EditText field and on clicking a button have it store in my SQLite Database Table with each one on it's own row. This would be ideal so that people with a big list (50-100) can mass insert data. Right now I have it to were it will insert a single name into my Table.

DatabaseHelper.java

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String TAG = "DatabaseHelper";

    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "hashtag_table";
    private static final String COL1 = "ID";
    private static final String COL2 = "name";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COL2 +" TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(createTable);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP IF TABLE EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }


    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, TABLE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    /**
     * Add data to the table
     * @param item
     * @return
     */
    public boolean addData(String item) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL2, item);

        Log.d(TAG, "addData: Adding " + item + " to " + TABLE_NAME);

        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

        if (result == -1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Gets the data from the table
     * @return
     */
    public Cursor getData() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
        Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        return data;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the ID from the table
     * @param name
     * @return
     */
    public Cursor getItemID(String name) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT " + COL1 + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + COL2 + " = '" + name + "'";
        Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query,null);
        return data;
    }

    /**
     * Updates the name from the table
     * @param newName
     * @param id
     * @param oldName
     */
    public void updateName(String newName, int id, String oldName) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "UPDATE " + TABLE_NAME + " SET " + COL2 + " = '" + newName + "' WHERE " + COL1 + " = '" + id + "'" + " AND " + COL2 + " = '" + oldName + "'";
        Log.d(TAG, "updateName: query: " + query);
        Log.d(TAG, "updateName: setting name to " + newName);
        db.execSQL(query);
    }

    /**
     * Deletes the name from the table
     * @param id
     * @param name
     */
    public void deleteName(int id, String name) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + COL1 + " = '" + id + "'" + " AND " + COL2 + " = '" + name + "'";
        Log.d(TAG, "deleteName: query: " + query);
        Log.d(TAG, "deleteName: Deleting " + name + " from database.");
        db.execSQL(query);
        db.execSQL("UPDATE SQLITE_SEQUENCE SET seq = 0 WHERE NAME = '"+TABLE_NAME+"'");
    }
}
```

ListView.java (where the editText and button is right now)

```
//Adds new hashtag to list and prompts if nothing is entered
    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String newEntry = editText.getText().toString();

            if (editText.length() != 0) {
                addData(newEntry);
                editText.setText("");
            } else {
                toastMessage("you must put something in the text field");
            }
        }
    });

    populateListView();
}

/**
 * Adds new data into the Database
 * @param newEntry
 */
public void addData(String newEntry) {
    boolean insertData = mDatabaseHelper.addData(newEntry);

    if (insertData) {
        toastMessage("Successfully inserted");
        recreate();
    } else {
        toastMessage("Whoops, something went wrong");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code isn't safe from SQL injection btw.

Comment: @Zoe actually it is protected from SQL injection, (escaped), as part of the insert convenience method's construction of the underlying SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a pretty basic replacement for the **addData** that uses the String's **[split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))** method to break the string into comma separated values and insert them :-

```
/**
 * Add data to the table
 *
 * @param item
 * @return
 */
public boolean addData(String item) {

    String[] splitdata = item.split(","); //<<<<<<<<<< split the input string
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

    boolean result = true;
    db.beginTransaction(); //<<<<<<<<<< prepare to do in a single transaction
    // Loop through each string inserting an entry into the database
    for (String s : splitdata) {
        contentValues.clear(); //<<<<<<<<<< clear any existing values to be safe
        contentValues.put(COL2, s);
        if (db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues) < 1) {
            result = false;
        }
    }
    if (result) {
        db.setTransactionSuccessful(); //<<<<<<<<<< only set the transaction successful if all inserts worked
    }
    db.endTransaction();
    return result;
}
```

Note that this will roll back all inserts if there are any failed inserts and additionally return a false.

- The above code is in principle code, it hasn't been tested or run and may therefore contains some errors.

Comment: you are so amazing! This worked perfectly. Thank you so much!

Comment: @NobleFinsand that's good, Could please tick the answer if you believe the answer helped you resolve the issue.

Comment: You got it! Thanks again!